# Convergence of improper integral: $x^2\cos(e^x)$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I am pretty sure the following converges, but I'm having trouble proving it.
$$\int_0^\infty x^2\cos(e^x)dx$$
I tried breaking up the integral into pieces, where each piece corresponds to a period of $\cos(e^x)$, but I'm stuck.

Any hints?

Edit: Later I'd like to extend the argument to other exponents, e.g. $\int_0^\infty x^{1000} \cos(e^x)$. I know that not every exponent works, but I think that exponents > -1 work.

Comment: For convergence you rely on the interval between two successive zeros shrinking much faster than the peak is rising. It should not be hard to formalise that into a rigorous argument.

Comment: That's definitely the picture that's been in my head, but I can't figure out a way to make that into a nice rigorous argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A start: Rewrite the integrand as $x^2e^{-x}e^x\cos(e^x)$, and integrate by parts, with $u=x^2e^{-x}$ and $dv=e^x\cos(e^x)\,dx$. Then $du=(-x^2e^{-x}+2xe^{-x})\,dx$ and we can take $v=\sin(e^x)$.

Comment: Ended up going in a circle with the integration by parts, but maybe that's just an error on my part.

Comment: I can write more detail if you wish. However, I can guess what you are trying to do, and would rather you finished the argument. After the first integration by parts, there is an integral remaining. **Do not attempt** to evaluate it, just show it exists. This should be relatively easy. For $\sin(e^x)$ stays between $-1$ and $1$, and the rest of the stuff decreases rapidly because of the $e^{-x}$, so the (improper) integral converges. To repeat, I am ready with more detail if you keep having difficulty.

Comment: Oh I see, I was trying to evaluate it. I'll take another look.

Comment: @animal_magic: Just saw your edit. Essentially the same argument will work for $x^{1000}\cos(e^x)$, because in the long run the $e^{-x}$ crushes any polynomial. For negative powers of $x$, the behaviour becomes simpler "at" $\infty$, but there is potential trouble at $0$. However, for $x^{-p}$ where $p\lt 1$, it is OK near $0$ by comparison.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x= \ln y.$ Your question is then the same as asking if

$$ \int_1^\infty (\ln y)^2 \cos y \frac{dy}{y}$$

converges. Because $(\ln y)^2/y$ is eventually decreasing, Dirichlet's test shows the answer is yes.

Comment: This is great thanks! I'll read up on Dirichlet's test.

Comment: Seems like this approach works as long as the exponent, call it $b$, is greater than or equal to zero ($b=2$ in the given problem). If $b<0$, then $\ln(y)^b/y$ is unbounded at 1. I believe that the integral converges for all $b>-1$, so this proof doesn't extend to that case. Of course, that isn't the problem I asked, just leaving this as a note (to myself and maybe others).